# Content Security Policy - data:image/svg+xml is ignored in img-src

Tags: content-security-policy

My CSP header looks like this (actually, it's only the part relevent to loading images), which should be valid. But Chrome complains that "The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'img-src' contains an invalid source: 'data:image/svg+xml'. It will be ignored."

```
img-src data:image/svg+xml 'self' https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect https://www.facebook.com/tr/ https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect data:image/svg+xml;
```

It should be valid, I've found it in examples around the web, yet it does not work. For example it is suggested here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94993/is-including-the-data-scheme-in-your-content-security-policy-safe/95011#95011

Please provide valid and working example, I am lost in this maze.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your example CSP is invalid. According to [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src) you should use only hosts, schemas or other constant values. After correction, you example should look like:

`img-src 'self' https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/ https://www.facebook.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ data:;`

Comment: Thank you! I've seen many examples where they recommend `data:image/svg+xml` to narrow down the opened area. But that did not work.

Comment: This also confused me, The selected InfoSec answer here confused things more, see the non-accepted but more upvoted answer for a better answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/167244/76413